# Can NLS_date format be used to get same result from different sessions?

Tags: plsql

```
create function inv_date return varchar2
result_cache authid definer is
demo_date varchar2(50);
begin
l_date := sysdate;
return l_date;
end;
```

Users of this function may set different date formats in their sessions. Which two modifications must be made to allow the use of your sessions date format when outputting the cached result of this function?

A. Change the RETURN type to DATE.
B. Change AUTHID to CURRENT_USER.
C. Use the TO_CHAR function around SYSDATE, that is, 1_date := TO_CHAR (SYSDATE).
D. Change the data type of 1_date to DATE.
E. Set NLS_DATE_FORMAT to ‘DD-MM-YY’ at the instance level.
F. Set the RESULT_CACHE_MODE parameter to FORCE.

Comment: I assume this is am exam or interview question you are having difficultly with. Since it small I suggest you actually write the routine.  Then make each change and run it, see what the results are. If in doing so you don't understand a result or cannot figure out then post a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

CE - According to me specifying a standard NLS_Date_formate and calling to_char on sysdate should resolve the issue.

AD - But while searching I saw that multiple sites are saying that changing the return type and data type of l_date is the solution.